# When I use Inner Join some of my rows are deleted

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I am joining Table A and Table B

```
Table A :                    Table B:
A  C                        A D 
1  3                        1 2
4  4                        4 5 
7  4                        7 9
```

My Code:

```
SELECT 
A.A,
A.C,
B.D
INTO TEST
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.A = B.A
```

My Result looks like this:

```
A C D
1 3 2
4 4 5
```

So it is some rows where C has the same number.
But why?

Comment: which data type are the columns A ??

Comment: They are from type string

Comment: I don't believe we would be able to reproduce this behavior using the data you showed us.  Please add a demo if you can.

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in a `varchar` column? Don't do that

Comment: Maybe column `A` is of type of `varchar` or `char` in one of these tables, and contains a value (seven + space) or (space + seven) while the other table contains single `7` without spaces.

Comment: is your question : why the row with values `7,4,9` is missing for the result ..?

Comment: Why? Because that's how SQL works. You don't need us to rewrite the manual & asking us would be no-research & not-useful & a duplicate. What do you expect for an answer? If you want us to address your wrong thinking then you need to tell us what you expected & why. PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

could be you have data type string and some hidden char  try trim  off  space

```
  SELECT 
  A.A,
  A.C,
  B.D
  FROM A INNER 
  JOIN B ON trim(A.A)  = trim(B.A)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would occur because what looks like `7` in the two tables is not exactly `7`.

I can readily think of two possibilities.

The first is that you are storing the values as floating point numbers.  So, "7" might really be "7.000000001" or "6.999999997", but it gets printed out as "7".

This is relatively easily fixed by doing something like this:

```
ON ABS(A.A - B.A) < 0.01
ON A.A BETWEEN B.A - 0.0001 AND B.A + 0.0001
ON CAST(A.A as int) = CAST(b.A as int)
```

(Note that these use different thresholds for equality.)

The second is that the values are strings and you have hidden characters of some sort -- spaces at the beginning or end of the string (some databases ignore these) or hidden characters from extended character sets.

This is harder to fix.  Spaces can be removed using `trim()`, but other characters require a bit more work -- and that depends on the database.